# Using post title in an array

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to use the `the_title()` function to get the title of a post and then reference that title in an array. Code is as follows:

```
    <?php
            $title = array( 
                the_title()
            );
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => array( 'questions' ), 'content' => array( $title )
            );
```

So I want to take the post title and use the `$args` variable to find posts that have post type = 'questions' and have the current post's title as their value for the 'content' taxonomy.

Currently it isn't working. The post I'm testing on has title 'Book1'and it works when I change the `$args` line to:

```
$args = array(
                'post_type' => array( 'questions' ), 'content' => array( 'Book1' )
```

But with the code I listed first, it doesn't work...

EDIT: yep, it was simple: just needed to change it to 'content' => $title because $title is already an array. Thanks all!

Comment: How is the `$args` array being used? Also, where is this code being used? Int the loop? Within a function hooked somewhere? Please edit the original question to show this code too. @ngcodex is right about using get_the_title() instead of the_title(), since the latter will echo output immediately.

Comment: `$title` is already an array - therefore this should be `'content' => $title`

Comment: Glad to hear that you fixed the problem, Rob. Please post your solution as an answer to your question, then stop by in a couple of days and click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it. This will close the question out of the unanswered question queue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use get_the_title() to store the title inside a variable.. the_title() would actually print the title ..

Comment: Ah, thanks! But unfortunately it still doesn't seem to work... have edited my original question to explain a little better

Answer (score 0):

Answer was simple in the end:

```
<?php
        $title = array( 
            the_title()
        );
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => array( 'questions' ), 'content' => $title
        );
```

So I just needed to change 'content' => array( $title) to simply 'content' => $title. This was because $title is already an array!

Thanks everyone for the help.